# Xcode command line tools (two versions side by side)

Tags: ios, xcode, appium, command-line-tool

Recently we've moved to Xcode 8 in order to compile the app with new Xcode version, but I still need to use Old Xcode (7.3.1) in order to use it's instruments with older ver of appium ...
 
I was wondering if there is a way to open each Xcode ver and to use it's relevant command line tools?
 currently , the command line tools I set in specific version is being used among two Xcode versions ...

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a particular version of Xcode (say Xcode 8) installed in your system, go to /Applications and rename it to something else like Xcode8 or Xcode7.3.1. Install the other version normally. Now you have both versions running in different names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using X-code 7.3.3. to run appium test and Xcode-8 to build app under test. I have moved xocde8 into folder name "xcode8". 
And to switch between different Xcode version you can use -

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/

sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/xcode8/Xcode-8.app/Contents/Developer/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a particular version of Xcode (say Xcode 8) installed in your system, go to /Applications and rename it to something else like Xcode8 or Xcode7.3.1. Install the other version normally. Now you have both versions running in different names.
I hope this is what you were looking for..